# Flutter - How to stop re-rendering of ListView.builder after scrolling out of view

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm building a Workout Tracker app using Flutter and Dart. On the tracking page are lists of exercises and a done Icon, when clicked, changes its color(To show that you're done with the set). Icon state changes locally in the file.

So the problem is when I scroll down, the upper items revert back to their original state.  Long story short, I don't want the icons to Rerender on demand and save their state until I want to.

Tried AutomaticKeepAliveStateMixin but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm a newbie in coding so maybe I am implementing it wrong.

```dart
class _ExerciseInputState extends State<ExerciseInput>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    var deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.loadedRoutine.exercises.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return buildExerciseContainer(
            widget.loadedRoutine.exercises[i].title,
            widget.loadedRoutine.exercises[i].sets,
            widget.loadedRoutine.exercises[i].reps,
            deviceSize,
            context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

No error messages.

Comment: where are you storing your `bool done` property?

Comment: Consider sharing your `buildExerciseContainer`also

Comment: @Martyns yes my bad. I had stored the buildExercisecontainer in another stateful widget. its works when I Do this in that stateful widget. Stupid Mistake